# Screen not scrolling down when using JQuery slidetoggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a site where there is a  called .slidingDiv which when the anchor .show_hide is clicked it appears and slides down which is great when it's the only content on the page.

If there is other content above this div it doesn't scroll down and show. Instead it shows the div but it is out of site, so it does actually work but not push the rest of the content up.

Here's the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(), 1000;
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    });

});

</script>
```

Many thanks

Pete

Comment: [JSHint](http://jshint.com) and the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) documentation helps often much...

Answer (score 9):

Setting `scrollTop` in the callback of the `slideToggle` function or after the `slideToggle` function has been called (as you have did) results in jumpy behavior, at best. If you are looking for a smooth animation it is best to initiate the slide then `animate` the page to scroll down. This is demonstrated by this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPXLF/). Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slidingDiv").hide();
  $(".show_hide").show();

  $('.show_hide').click(function() {
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(1000);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".slidingDiv").offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, 2000);
  });
});​
```

Comment: following this script, after the div is toggled, and the screen scrolled down, I can scroll back up after a few tries, and the page gets jumpy, like it does not let me to scroll.

Comment: This fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/d5590q4u/, confirms that the scrollTop value is set beyond the max value. If the animation is given time to complete the scroll position is updated and the jumpy behavior goes away. This is not a good solution, there has to be a better way to solve this problem. If you need more help, I suggest asking a new SO question.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a check before scrollTop

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".slidingDiv").hide();
 $(".show_hide").show();

 $('.show_hide').on('click',function(){
  $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(function(){
   if($('.slidingDiv').height() > 0) {
    $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(".slidingDiv").offset().top
       }, 1000);
   }
  });
 });

});

</script>
```